# Multiple long positions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am a begginer in Pine script. I would like to know how to make my strategy to open a new long position even if the previous long position has not closed. I want the strategy to open a new long position every time the long coditions are met.
Many thanks!

---

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you have to decide the maximum number of long position you will accept as a maximum (with the pyramiding parameter).
For example for 10 Long orders max:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", pyramiding = 10)
```

Then, each time you want to enter a long, use strategy.entry().
Note that you can cumul order ONLY if they are in the same direction ( Long or Short exclusivly).
See : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html#order-placement-commands